# PHP w/ JSON data returns Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: php, json, api

PHP script to connect to 3rd Party API with very little documentation (https://www.youvegotleads.com/webservices/documentation) returns an error from API that I am not familiar with.  I've consulted and searched and tried to implement several suggested solutions to no avail.

```
$host = "https://www.youvegotleads.com/api/properties/95774/leads";

$header = array();
$header[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string);
$header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$header[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$header[] = 'Authorization: Basic eWdsQXBpVGVzdDM6cGFzc3dvcmQ=';
$header[] = 'Hostname: https://www.youvegotleads.com';

    //if($form["id"] == 1){//Join Our Mailing List
    //$entry["6"]
    $data = array(
     "Veteran" => 'Yes',
     "PrimaryContact" => array (
     "FirstName" =>     "Tommy",
     "LastName" =>     "Tuba", 
     "Address" => array (
         "Email" =>          "tommy@tubas.com",
         "PhoneHome" =>      "555-555-1212",
         "PhoneCell" =>      "555-555-1313",
         "PhoneWork" =>      "555-555-1414"
      ),
     "DateOfBirth" => "07/18/1950"
     ),
     );
//}

 $data_string = json_encode($data); 


    $ch = curl_init($host);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
    // 3. execute and fetch the resulting HTML output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($output);
    echo "</pre>";


    if ($output === FALSE) {
         echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
     }

    // 4. free up the curl handle
    curl_close($ch);
```

Error returned from API:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"   at YouveGotLeads.Areas.WebServices.Controllers.LeadsController.PostLead(Int32 propertyId, L
```

Comment: That looks a java error in their code. You probably need to contact them. It's possible that you're not sending the right data, but with poor documentation that's usually hard to figure out. If they are a small organization they might be able to work with you, esp since other people are probably going through the same thing. But it's not likely that anyone outside of their organization will know what that problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  Yes, they don't have  much in the way of documentation.  No Libaries or Wrappers.  They are using AJAX requests in their own demos.  The only difference I can see is that since I am using PHP to perform the API call and they are using Javascript that the JSON Objects are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed it again and it was an error in their API.